# How Can I Combine NG-TEMPLATE, NG-FOR, NG-IF with a Child Component

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content

I have the following scenario...

```
// child-component.ts
@Input() attrOne: any;
@Input() attrTwo: any;
isVisible: boolean = true;

HideThis(){
  this.isVisible = false;
}
```

And...

```
// child-component.html
<div *ngIf="isVisible">
  <!-- nested content -->
  <span (click)="HideThis()">Hide This</span>
</div>
```

Then...

```
// parent-component.html
// listData comes from server as is...
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of listData">
  <child-component [attrOne]="item.propOne" [attrTwo]="item.propTwo"></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

A child component, let's call it **child-component**, is embedded in **parent-component**. I use an ng-for on **parent-component** to list an array of data using the embedded child-component... I need to be able to do **(click)="HideThis()"** on any of the child-component embedded... My attempt (as above) hides the content but leaves a blank **child-component** element in the DOM of **parent-component** when I click HideThis(). I wish to completely remove or avoid listing the respective child-component.

I cannot use a property like listData[n].item.prop to do *ngIf test. listData comes from a remote server. Is there a way to avoid using something like `@Output() onHidden: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();`

I've tried **ng-template** and **ng-content** to little avail. What's the best way?

Answer (score 0):

You can put *ngFor on the component itself without extra wrappers:

```
<child-component *ngFor="let item of listData" [attrOne]="item.propOne" [attrTwo]="item.propTwo"></child-component>
```

> I cannot use a property like listData[n].item.prop

actually you can but doing:

```
<child-component *ngFor="let item of listData" [attrOne]="item.propOne; let i = index" [attrTwo]="item.propTwo"></child-component>
```

but don't think that's the correct approach

if you need more detailed answer - please create a stackblitz sandbox for it

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me. This was the natural first attempt - without ng-container... I suppose the solution must use the *ngIf  test at the parent-component list but am trying to avoid using @Output() from child-component.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to completely remove the `<app-child>` selector from the DOM, the condition should be included in the parent component, not the child.

parent.component.ts

```js
listData: {propOne: string, propTwo: string, visible: boolean}[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.getList().pipe(
    map(response => { response.forEach(item => item['visible'] = true })
  ).subscribe(
    list => { this.listData = list },
    error => { }
  );
}
```

parent.component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="listData">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listData">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.visible">
      <app-child [attrOne]="item.propOne" [attrTwo]="item.propTwo"></app-child>
      <button (mouseup)="item.visible = false">Click here to hide</button>
    <ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Now the `isVisible` property isn't required in the child component anymore.

Naturally this hides the child component forever if it's clicked. You could change it to a toggle function by bumping the button one level outer and in the callback toggle the flag instead of setting it to `false`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="listData">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of listData">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.visible">
      <app-child [attrOne]="item.propOne" [attrTwo]="item.propTwo"></app-child>
    <ng-container>
    <button (mouseup)="item.visible = !item.visible">Click here to hide</button>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This means I will have to change the listData coming from the server to add "visible" property... It's undesirable but may work. Still wonder if there is no better way.